# Set Background Gradient Color on View in TableViewCell in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, uicolor

How can i achieve this type of Gradient color I try many thing but i don't achieve this type of gradient color.Please help me .Thanks for consider me....

[image]

Here is my Code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell:HomeTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! HomeTableViewCell!
        //  let  image : UIImageView = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = cell.bgView.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor (colorLiteralRed: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3), UIColor(red:0.51, green:0.53, blue:0.53, alpha:0.3)].map { $0.cgColor }
        gradient.locations = [0.0,1.0]
        cell.bgView?.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this is to use layer image and you can get exact result you desire.

Comment: is you bgView is in front of image view?